# Which test-coverge tool for Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++, code-coverage, gcov

The main product of our organization has been developed(and being developed) in C/C++ over the past 10 years. The compiler used is Microsoft Visual Studio (cl) for the same.

We need a **test-coverage tool** (identical to **gcov**) for checking the coverage of the code. As per my understanding, gcov only works with g++ family of compilers and hence will **not work with Visual Studio's compiler**. (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Now, since we can't change the compiler; please suggest a test-coverage tool which will work in our case.

Thanks.

Comment: Intel C++ includes test coverage as a plug-in to Visual Studio (not identical to gcov).

Comment: @tim18 the plugin won't do as the OP is looking for something identical to `gcov` which is all console based, which makes it easier to automate the coverage process for regular usage.